# Me da un error al intentar usar el método Colections.sort() de un Vector

Tags: java

Me esta volviendo loco el error siguiente:

> The method `sort(List<T>)` in the type Collections is not applicable for
>   the arguments (`Vector<Cliente>`).

La primera clase que tengo es mi main, que crea un objeto empresa; le añadí un juego de pruebas, también tiene un menú que va accediendo a los métodos.

La opcion 5 es la que me falla:

```
 empresa.ordenarListaClientes();
```

Me lleva a la clase empresa.

Principal

```
package ejercicio3Colecciones;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        // C L I E N T E S

        Cliente cli1 = new Cliente("Cli1","c/ pez",3000.0);
        Cliente cli2 = new Cliente("Cli2","c/ pajaro",30001.0);
        Cliente cli3 = new Cliente("Cli3","c/ perro",29000.0);

        empresa.coleccionClientes.listaClientes.add(cli1);
        empresa.coleccionClientes.listaClientes.add(cli2);



        // P R O Y E C TO S

        Proyecto pro1= new Proyecto("telefonica", false);
        Proyecto pro2= new Proyecto("MadridTaxis", true);
        Proyecto pro3= new Proyecto("Repsol", true);
        Proyecto pro4 = new Proyecto("ProyectoParam", true);
        Proyecto pro5 = new Proyecto("Proyecto34", false);

        empresa.coleccionProyectos.listaProyectos.add(pro1);
        empresa.coleccionProyectos.listaProyectos.add(pro2);
        empresa.coleccionProyectos.listaProyectos.add(pro3);
        empresa.coleccionProyectos.listaProyectos.add(pro4);
        empresa.coleccionProyectos.listaProyectos.add(pro5);



        //P E R S O N A L

        Personal per1= new Programador("Lucia",cli2) ;
        Personal per2 = new Programador("Pedro", cli1);
        Personal per3 = new Responsable("Pablo", cli3);

        empresa.coleccionPersonal.listaPersonal.add(per1);
        empresa.coleccionPersonal.listaPersonal.add(per2);
        empresa.coleccionPersonal.listaPersonal.add(per3);


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int opcion;

        do {
            do {
                System.out.println("Elige una opción:" + "\n    1. Alta personal." + "\n    2. Asignar un Proyecto." + "\n  3. Visualizar Proyectos de programadores." + "\n    4. Ordenar lista clientes." + "\n   5. Serializar listar Clientes listar Personal ListarProyectos ."
                        + "\n   6. Salir.");
                opcion = in.nextInt();
            } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 6);

            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                //  objeto.metodo(in);
                empresa.altaPersonal(in);

                break;
            case 2:
                //objeto.metodo(in);
                empresa.asignarProyecto(in);

                break;
            case 3:
                //objeto.metodo(in);;
                empresa.visualizarProyectosProgramadores();
                break;
            case 4:
                //Metodos
                empresa.ordenarListaClientes();


                break;
            case 5:
                //Metodos
                empresa.coleccionClientes.recorrer();
                empresa.coleccionPersonal.recorrer();
                empresa.coleccionProyectos.recorrer();
                break;

            }
        } while (opcion != 6);

        in.close();
    }

}
```

Clase Empresa:

En esta clase tengo tres atributos `coleccionClientes`, `coleccionPersonal`, `coleccionProyectos`, donde cada una tiene un objeto colección.

La que nos interesa seria `coleccionClientes` la cual tiene un `Vector`.
tambien nos interesa el método `ordenarListaClientes()`:

```
package ejercicio3Colecciones;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Empresa {
    ColeccionClientes coleccionClientes = new ColeccionClientes();
    ListaPersonal coleccionPersonal = new ListaPersonal();
    ListaProyectos coleccionProyectos = new ListaProyectos();

    public void altaPersonal(Scanner in){
        Personal personalAux;
        Cliente clienteAux;
        String tipoPersonal;

        tipoPersonal = validarPersonal_P_R(in);

        System.out.println("Dame un Cliente que ya exista");
        String nombreCliente = in.next();
        clienteAux=coleccionClientes.buscarCliente(nombreCliente);//busco en lista clientes

        if (clienteAux==null) {
            System.out.println("Cliente no existente");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Cliente existente");    
            System.out.println("Dame el nombre del trabajador");
            String nombre=in.next();

            if (tipoPersonal.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
            personalAux = new Programador(nombre, clienteAux);//new programador
            coleccionPersonal.insertarPersonal(personalAux);//inserto

            }else {
            personalAux = new Responsable(nombre, clienteAux);//new responsble
            coleccionPersonal.insertarPersonal(personalAux);//inserto 
            }

        }




    }

    public void asignarProyecto(Scanner in){
        Personal personalAux;

        System.out.println("Dame el registro personal de un trabajador");
        String registroPersonal = in.next();

        personalAux=coleccionPersonal.buscarPersonal(registroPersonal);

        coleccionProyectos.buscarPrioridadAltaEnLista(personalAux);
        personalAux.buscarProyectoPrioridadAlta();

    }

    public void visualizarProyectosProgramadores() {
        //1- listo solo los programadores
        coleccionPersonal.recorrerSoloProg_ySusProyectos();


    }
    public void ordenarListaClientes(){


        coleccionClientes.ordenar();
    }



    private String validarPersonal_P_R(Scanner in) {
        String tipoPersonal;
        System.out.println("Quieres dar de alta un programador o un responsable P/R");
        do {
            tipoPersonal=in.next();
            if (!(tipoPersonal.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) && !(tipoPersonal.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))) {
                System.out.println("no has introducido un tipo correcto vuelve a insertarlo P/R");
            }
        } while (!(tipoPersonal.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) && !(tipoPersonal.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) );
        return tipoPersonal;

    }





}
```

Por fin llegamos a nuestra clase coleccion clientes la cual tiene un vector de clientes. 
Tenemos nuestro constructor de la clase sin parametros y con un new  del vector.

en teoria aqui es 
donde usaria el metodo colecctions.sort(listaClientes) pero me salta el error del principio

> The method sort(`List<T>`) in the type Collections is not applicable for
>   the arguments (`Vector<Cliente>`).

```
package ejercicio3Colecciones;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ColeccionClientes {
     Vector<Cliente> listaClientes;


    public ColeccionClientes() {
        this.listaClientes = new Vector<Cliente>();
    }

    public Vector<Cliente> getListaClientes() {
        return listaClientes;
    }

    public void setListaClientes(Vector<Cliente> listaClientes) {
        this.listaClientes = listaClientes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListaClientes [listaClientes=" + listaClientes + "]";
    }

    public Cliente buscarCliente(String nombreCliente) {

        boolean encontrado = false;
        Cliente clienteAux = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size() && !encontrado; i++) {
            if (listaClientes.get(i) != null && listaClientes.get(i).getNombreCliente().compareTo(nombreCliente) == 0) {
                encontrado = true;
                clienteAux = listaClientes.get(i);
            }
        }
        return clienteAux;
    }


    public void insertarCliente() { }
    public void borrarCliente() {  }

    public void recorrer() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(listaClientes.get(i).toString());
        }

    }

    public void ordenar() {
        Collections.sort(listaClientes);


    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La clase Cliente cumple la interfaz Comparable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La clase `Vector`, al igual que `ArrayList` (te recomiendo que uses ésta en su lugar), cumplen la interfaz `List`, que contiene el método `sort`.
Cuando llamas a `Collections.sort(list)`, internamente lo que se hace es llamar a `list.sort(null)`.

Si miramos el método [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) de `Vector`, tenemos que:

> If the specified comparator is null **then all elements in this list must implement the Comparable interface** and the elements' natural ordering should be used

Traducción aproximada: Puesto que no declaras un comparador, se espera que los elementos sean [Comparables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) por sí solos, lo que obliga a implementar la interfaz correspondiente

Comment: Me ayudo mucho la respuesta